# Ordering and Removing Columns from List Views

Tags: cme, gui-extensions

I have created a new DataExtender to display a custom field for my items, and this column has been added to an editor and it works correctly in the CME.

However I would now like to remove one of the default columns, and control where my custom column shows (in my case just before the 'From Publication' column. Does anyone have an example config which shows how to position and remove custom columns?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to define `remove` section into `lists` section

```
            <ext:lists>
                <ext:remove>

                    <!-- Defines an extension to remove from the runtime
                        @id Defines an ID of the element to remove
                        @name Defines the extension name 
                    -->
                    <ext:extension id="NamedType" name="UIBeardcore.RemoveIconColumn">

                        <!-- The `apply` element defines the applicability for this extension -->
                        <ext:apply>
                            <ext:view name="DashboardView">
                                <ext:control id="FilteredItemsList" />
                            </ext:view>
                        </ext:apply>
                    </ext:extension>
                </ext:remove>
            </ext:lists>
```

Find a config
https://github.com/UIBeardcore/UIBeardcore.Extension.List/blob/master/Configuration/UIBeardcore.Extension.List.Editor.config

and video which describes list extensibility points (how-to remove colums topic starts from 3:15)
http://tridion.uibeardcore.com/2013/06/list/